# Most pythonic way to treat imported function override conflict

Tags: python, overriding

I am importing two different modules that both override the standard math functions, e.g. log(). I have a few different ways to resolve this conflict. Which would be the most pythonic?

Option 1:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import casadi

def coolFunction():
    pyomo_x = Var()
    pyomo_f = log(x)

def niceFunction():
    casadi_x = casadi.SX.sym('x')
    casadi_f = casadi.log(x)
```

Option 2:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

def coolFunction():
    pyomo_x = Var()
    pyomo_f = log(x)

def niceFunction():
    from casadi import *
    casadi_x = SX.sym('x')
    casadi_f = casadi.log(x)
```

Option 3:

```
???
```

Comment: Don't use `*` and you won't have the problem, you are polluting your namespace, import what you want explicitly giving an alias if needed

Comment: Yuck. the `using namespace std;` of Python.

Comment: Option 3 is definitely better.

Comment: Doing `from some_module import *` is bad enough when you're only importing one module since it pollutes your namespace with all the names defined in `some_module`. But doing it with 2 or more modules is a recipe for disaster due to the potential for name conflicts between the modules, and there's no way to prevent that conflict. So _please_ avoid using  `from some_module import *` in your scripts. OTOH, it _can_ be handy for doing a quick test, especially in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Option 2 is a syntax error in Python 3. You can only use `from module import *` at the top level, not within a function. Not that it's really a good idea anywhere, mind you.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that the tutorial/class from which you learned Python made you think that the `from module import *` method was the only way to import from a module.

Comment: While in general I can certainly see cause for avoidance of `import *`, in this particular case Pyomo is effectively a modeling language built on top of python, where pyomo.environ is a module crafted specifically to build a particular namespace for the language. I had forgotten about the `as` renaming functionality; for that I thank those who have answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `from something import *`. Either use `import something` or `from something import foo, bar, ...`.

If you want to import functions the second way, and two functions with the same name from two different modules, you can write:

```
from module_a import log as a_log
from module_b import log as b_log
```

As PM 2Ring pointed out in the comments, you can also use `as` to rename the modules to something shorter, in order to keep the hierarchy:

```
import module_a as ma
import module_b as mb
...
ma.log(...)
```

Comment: Another option is to import the module with a short name. Eg, `import module_a as ma`, lets you do `ma.log(x)` instead of `module_a.log(x)`

Comment: You can use that with `from ...` as well; `from module_a import log as ma_log`.

Answer (score 3):

Just import the modules and give them clear and short names, e.g.:

```
import pyomo.environ as omo
import casadi

def coolFunction():
    pyomo_x = omo.Var()
    pyomo_f = omo.log(x)

def niceFunction():
    casadi_x = casadi.SX.sym('x')
    casadi_f = casadi.log(x)
```

Don't use `from xy import *` or imports inside of functions. You should always see at once, which names are imported and which dependencies a module has.